# accessing static html css and javascript inside a react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have my react app directory structure like this.

[image]

I am using react-router to display some tabs in my app and in one of the tabs, I want to display static HTML /CSS and Javascript contents in one of my tab.

My `src/main` folder contains the following folders:

1. `js` folder with all react app-related JS components
2. `resources/static` folder with `images` folder and one random `index.html` file which is not used.

**Approach 1:**

I am wondering if I can put my static HTML /CSS and Javascript contents inside the `resources/static` folder or should I create a `webapp` folder and put it in there, and after putting it there, would I be able to access the contents inside my tab using `Iframe`?

**Approach 2:**
The other way which has worked for me is the following:

I put the static html,css and javascript in a folder(`ProjectExternal`) inside webapps folder of tomcat. And then access it like this from my react tab:

```
<Iframe
                url="https://mycurrentserver/ProjectExternal/index.html"
                width='100%'
                //height='500%'
                height='830px'
                allowFullScreen
            />
```

If I can get it through `Approach 1` then I won't have to go through the time-consuming process of `Approach 2` of putting files and folders somewhere else and accessing it from there